# Fundamental group of collapsed cube skeleton

Tags: algebraic-topology

I’m having trouble solving this exercise.

> Let $C=[0,1]^3$ be the standard cube in $\mathbb{R}^3$
>   And let $X$ be the edges.
>   Now I should compute the fundamental group of $Y$ where $Y$ is obtained collapsing the 3 edges of $X$ with an extremity in the origin to a point.

I tried to use van Kampen but I don’t know which open set consider.

[image: picture]

Comment: Did you mean "...its sides" in the definition of $\;X\;$ ? And what **the** three sides of the cube are you collapsing? Perhaps posting a picture can help to make your question clearer.

Comment: Sorry my English isn’t very good, I men it’s sides and i’m collapsing all the sides that have an extreme in the origin to a point

Comment: The text is still unclear, at least for me. Maybe it is a good idea to draw the graph of the sides, it is planar, put a square $ABCD$ on the piece of paper, an other one "around it" (obtained by a homothety of factor $2$ w.r.t. the center of $ABCD$), call the second square $A'B'C'D'$, and also join $AA'$, $BB'$, $CC'$, $DD'$. Now, what are we collapsing? How many simple cycles remain in the graph?

Comment: So...what is the role of $\;X\;$ in the question??

Comment: $X$ is the set of the side of the cube, i’m collapsing 3 side of $X$ I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

We have a homotopy $H_t([(x,y,z)])=[(tx,ty,tz)]$ between $\operatorname{id}_Y$ and $pt$, i.e., $Y$ is contractible.  So $\pi_1(Y)$ is trivial.

---

**Edit**: OP clarified it was $X/\sim$ rather than $C/\sim$.  In this case, $\pi_1(X/\sim)=\pi_1(X)=\pi_1(S^2-\text{ 6 points})$ is the free group on 5 generators.

Comment: I’m only considering the side of the cube.

Comment: updated answer.

Comment: Why is $S^2-$ 6 points , I don’t have the face of the cube I only have its side

Comment: He only has the edges. Faces are holes.

Comment: First, $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a "thicken" version where you take a neighbourhood of the edges in the faces.  Now use homotopy equivalence of "enlarging/shrinking the hole"